# Sagemaker - batch transform] Internal server error : 500

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to do a batch transform on a training dataset in an S3 bucket. I have followed this link:
https://github.com/aws-samples/quicksight-sagemaker-integration-blog

The training data on which transformation is being applied is of ~35 MB.
I am getting these errors:

1. Bad HTTP status received from algorithm: 500
2. The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Process followed:

```
1. s3_input_train = sagemaker.TrainingInput(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/rawtrain/'.format(bucket, prefix), content_type='csv')

2. from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
script_path = 'preprocessing.py'
sklearn_preprocessor = SKLearn(
entry_point=script_path,
role=role,
train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
framework_version='0.20.0',
py_version = 'py3',
sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
sklearn_preprocessor.fit({'train': s3_input_train})

3. transform_train_output_path = 's3://{}/{}/{}/'.format(bucket, prefix, 'transformtrain-train-output')
scikit_learn_inferencee_model = sklearn_preprocessor.create_model(env={'TRANSFORM_MODE': 'feature-transform'})
transformer_train = scikit_learn_inferencee_model.transformer(
instance_count=1,
assemble_with = 'Line',
output_path = transform_train_output_path,
accept = 'text/csv',
strategy = "MultiRecord",
max_payload =40,
instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')

4. Preprocess training input
transformer_train.transform(s3_input_train.config['DataSource']['S3DataSource']['S3Uri'], 
                            content_type='text/csv',
                            split_type = "Line")
print('Waiting for transform job: ' + transformer_train.latest_transform_job.job_name)
transformer_train.wait()
preprocessed_train_path = transformer_train.output_path + transformer_train.latest_transform_job.job_name

preprocessing.py

from __future__ import print_function

import time
import sys
from io import StringIO
import os
import shutil

import argparse
import csv
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import logging

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Binarizer, StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder

from sagemaker_containers.beta.framework import (
    content_types, encoders, env, modules, transformer, worker)

# Specifying the column names here.
feature_columns_names = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G',
    'H',
    'I',
    'J',
    'K'
] 

label_column = 'ab'

feature_columns_dtype = {
    'A' :  str,
    'B' :  np.float64,
    'C' :  np.float64,
    'D' :  str,
    "E" :  np.float64,
    'F' :  str,
    'G' :  str,
    'H' :  np.float64,
    'I' :  str,
    'J' :  str,
    'K':  str,
}

label_column_dtype = {'ab': np.int32}  

def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()   # start with x's keys and values
    z.update(y)    # modifies z with y's keys and values & returns None
    return z

def _is_inverse_label_transform():
    """Returns True if if it's running in inverse label transform."""
    return os.getenv('TRANSFORM_MODE') == 'inverse-label-transform'

def _is_feature_transform():
    """Returns True if it's running in feature transform mode."""
    return os.getenv('TRANSFORM_MODE') == 'feature-transform'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Sagemaker specific arguments. Defaults are set in the environment variables.
    parser.add_argument('--output-data-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'])


    args = parser.parse_args()

    input_files = [ os.path.join(args.train, file) for file in os.listdir(args.train) ]
    if len(input_files) == 0:
        raise ValueError(('There are no files in {}.\n' +
                          'This usually indicates that the channel ({}) was incorrectly specified,\n' +
                          'the data specification in S3 was incorrectly specified or the role specified\n' +
                          'does not have permission to access the data.').format(args.train, "train"))

    raw_data = [ pd.read_csv(
        file, 
        header=None,
        names=feature_columns_names + [label_column],
        dtype=merge_two_dicts(feature_columns_dtype, label_column_dtype)) for file in input_files ]
    concat_data = pd.concat(raw_data)
    
    numeric_features = list([
    'B',
    'C',
    'E',
    'H'
    ])


    numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

    categorical_features = list(['A','D','F','G','I','J','K'])
    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
            ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)],
        remainder="drop")

    preprocessor.fit(concat_data)

    joblib.dump(preprocessor, os.path.join(args.model_dir, "model.joblib"))

    print("saved model!")
    
    
def input_fn(input_data, request_content_type):
    """Parse input data payload
    
    We currently only take csv input. Since we need to process both labelled
    and unlabelled data we first determine whether the label column is present
    by looking at how many columns were provided.
    """
    
    
    content_type = request_content_type.lower(
    ) if request_content_type else "text/csv"
    content_type = content_type.split(";")[0].strip()
    
    
    if isinstance(input_data, str):
        str_buffer = input_data
    else:
        str_buffer = str(input_data,'utf-8')
    

    if _is_feature_transform():
        if content_type == 'text/csv':
            # Read the raw input data as CSV.
            df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input_data),  header=None)
            if len(df.columns) == len(feature_columns_names) + 1:
                # This is a labelled example, includes the  label
                df.columns = feature_columns_names + [label_column]
            elif len(df.columns) == len(feature_columns_names):
                # This is an unlabelled example.
                df.columns = feature_columns_names
            return df
        else:
            raise ValueError("{} not supported by script!".format(content_type))
    
    
    if _is_inverse_label_transform():
        if (content_type == 'text/csv' or content_type == 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'):
            # Read the raw input data as CSV.
            df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str_buffer),  header=None)
            if len(df.columns) == len(feature_columns_names) + 1:
            # This is a labelled example, includes the ring label
               df.columns = feature_columns_names + [label_column]
            elif len(df.columns) == len(feature_columns_names):
            # This is an unlabelled example.
               df.columns = feature_columns_names
            return df
        else:
            raise ValueError("{} not supported by script!".format(content_type))
            
            
def output_fn(prediction, accept):
    """Format prediction output
    
    The default accept/content-type between containers for serial inference is JSON.
    We also want to set the ContentType or mimetype as the same value as accept so the next
    container can read the response payload correctly.
    """
    
    accept = 'text/csv'
    if type(prediction) is not np.ndarray:
        prediction=prediction.toarray()
    
   
    if accept == "application/json":
        instances = []
        for row in prediction.tolist():
            instances.append({"features": row})

        json_output = {"instances": instances}

        return worker.Response(json.dumps(json_output), mimetype=accept)
    elif accept == 'text/csv':
        return worker.Response(encoders.encode(prediction, accept), mimetype=accept)
    else:
        raise RuntimeException("{} accept type is not supported by this script.".format(accept))


def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    """Preprocess input data
    
    We implement this because the default predict_fn uses .predict(), but our model is a preprocessor
    so we want to use .transform().

    The output is returned in the following order:
    
        rest of features either one hot encoded or standardized
    """

    
    if _is_feature_transform():
        features = model.transform(input_data)


        if label_column in input_data:
            # Return the label (as the first column) and the set of features.
            return np.insert(features.toarray(), 0, pd.get_dummies(input_data[label_column])['True.'], axis=1)
        else:
            # Return only the set of features
            return features
    
    if _is_inverse_label_transform():
        features = input_data.iloc[:,0]>0.5
        features = features.values
        return features
    

def model_fn(model_dir):
    """Deserialize fitted model
    """
    if _is_feature_transform():
        preprocessor = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
        return preprocessor
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are referring to a post that is pretty old and has issues open on Github [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/quicksight-sagemaker-integration-blog/issues) with regards to the Input source and the configurations.

I encourage you to check out the latest examples here which shows how to visualize Amazon SageMaker machine learning predictions with Amazon QuickSight.

Additionally, if the problem persists please open a service request with AWS Support with job ARN to investigate future on the Internal Server Error.